# Running glob and os on remote machine (pexpect session)

Tags: python, linux, glob, pexpect, os.path

I am trying to find a file locally and if i cannot find i want to remote to a machine and check if it is there.

Locally i can do using say for example:

```
 glob.glob(file_location)
```

In case i cant find it here i will ssh to a machine

```
 remote_machine = pexpect.spawn("ssh XX.XX.XX.XX.XX")
```

Now on this machine is there a way(or trick) we can use the same standard library function (os.XX , glob.XXX etc)?

```
 remote_machine.glob.glob(file_location)
```

Thanks in advance.